# Spring JPA Transaction ID

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have added an attribute to all my entities - transaction id - which is a sequence generated value that I bump up once in each transaction.

I also store the transaction id with user and start/end times so I have an audit trail for every change in the database.

What is the best way to handle storing a complete graph, where I basically only want to apply the transaction id to those entities that are actually dirty?

I can put a @PrePersist and @PreUpdate on the transaction id column, but how do I retrieve the value for the current transaction id?  Is there a way to store and retrieve a value on the transaction object or other JPA controller?  Do I need to use a ThreadLocal solution?

Comment: I did try a ThreadLocal implementation of this, and found it worked for persist, but not - or at least not always - for update.  I believe that the actual update is deferred until commit time, which occurs after my code has come and gone.  Unfortunately then, my ThreadLocal value has been removed.  I guess the next step is to not clear it in the entity control code, but rather clear it on a postcommit listener... I will see if I can make this work, but appreciate any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I did.  It seems to work in all of the use cases, though I have not done any performance testing, etc.  If anyone sees anything that may be non-optimal or may fail in certain situations, please point it out.

Here is the base service class that all @Service implementations must extend:

```
public class BaseService
{

    private final ActivityService activityService;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public static ThreadLocal<Activity> transaction = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public BaseService(ActivityService activityService, ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher)
    {
        this.activityService = activityService;
        this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
    }

    Object executeWithinActivity(Updater updater)
    {
        boolean startedLocally = false;
        try
        {
            if (transaction.get() == null)
            {
                startedLocally = true;
                Activity activity = activityService.startTransaction();
                transaction.set(activity);
            }
            return updater.execute(transaction.get());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (startedLocally)
            {
                applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new TransactionEvent());
                Activity activity = transaction.get();
                activityService.endTransaction(activity);
            }
        }
    }

    protected interface Updater
    {
        Object execute (Activity activity);
    }

    static class TransactionEvent
    {
    }
}
```

Activity is the entity that represents the stored transaction id:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@Table(name = "transactions", schema = "public", catalog = "euamdb")
public class Activity
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "transaction_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "tx_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "tx_generator", sequenceName = "transaction_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long transactionId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 24)
    private String userId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "transaction_start")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date transactionStart;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "transaction_end")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date transactionEnd;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Activity)) return false;
        Activity that = (Activity) o;
        return transactionId == that.transactionId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Long.hashCode(transactionId);
    }
}
```

ActivityService (which does not extend BaseService):

```
@Service
public class ActivityService
{
    private final ActivityRepository activityRepository;
    private final AuthUserService authService;

    @Autowired
    public ActivityService(ActivityRepository activityRepository, AuthUserService authService)
    {
        this.activityRepository = activityRepository;
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Activity startTransaction()
    {
        Activity activity = new Activity();
        activity.setTransactionStart(new Date());
        activity.setUserId(authService.getAuthenticatedUserId());
        activityRepository.save(activity);
        return activity;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void endTransaction(Activity activity)
    {
        activity.setTransactionEnd(new Date());
        activityRepository.save(activity);
    }
}
```

The base entity class for all entities (excepting Activity):

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter @Setter
public class BaseEntity
{
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "transaction_id")
    private Long transactionId;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void setupTransaction ()
    {
        ThreadLocal<Activity> transaction = BaseService.transaction;
        Activity activity = transaction.get();
        long transactionId = activity.getTransactionId();
        setTransactionId(transactionId);
    }
}
```

An example of a service:

```
@Service
public class OrganizationService extends BaseService
{
    private final OrgUserRepository orgUserRepository;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public OrganizationService(ActivityService activityService,
                               OrgUserRepository orgUserRepository,
                               UserService userService,
                               ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher)
    {
        super(activityService, applicationEventPublisher);
        this.orgUserRepository = orgUserRepository;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Transactional
    public OrgUser save(User user, OrgUser orgUser)
    {
        return (OrgUser) executeWithinActivity(activity ->
                              {
                                  orgUser.setUser(userService.save(user));
                                  return orgUserRepository.save(orgUser);
                              });
    }
}
```

UserService also will extend BaseService and the save(OrgUser) method will also executeWithinActivity.

Finally, the commit listener:

```
@Component
public class AfterCommitListener
{
    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION)
    public void doAfterTxComplete(BaseService.TransactionEvent event)
    {
        BaseService.transaction.remove();
    }
}
```